# Unable to show the data in django-mapbox-location-field Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I hope you all great!
I'm trying this module
https://github.com/simon-the-shark/django-mapbox-location-field

and I'm so confused about how can I add a field in my registration form below using this module.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<h1>Create Auction</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
    <form action="{% url 'auctions:create' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% if error_message %}<p class="error"><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
        <span>Enter title:</span>
        <span class="required_field" >*</span>
        <br>
        <input class="textbox" type="text" name="title">
        <br>
        <br>
        <span>Enter description:</span>
        <br>
        <input class="description_box" type="text" name="description">
        <br>
        <br>
        <span>Upload picture:</span>
        <br>
        <input class="textbox" type="file" accept="image/*" name="image">
        <br>
        <br>
        <span>Enter minimum value:</span>
        <span class="required_field" >*</span>
        <br>
        <input class="textbox" type="text" name="min_value">
        <br>
        <br>


        <input type="submit" class="submit_button" name="submit_button" value="Create">
    </form>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

I tried to add this in my form but it won't work, nothing shows!

```
<form method="post"> {% csrf_token %} 
   {{form}}
   <input type="submit" value="submit"> 
</form> 
{{ form.media }}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how much you know about django forms, but if your code works in admin panel, then I suppose you have used a model field.

## Model field definition (optional)

So assuming you have a model `Place` with `location` field. Something like this:

```py
class Place(models.Model):  
  location = LocationField()
```

If you have significantly different setup - just let me know and will try to adapt. But basically you can create a form also without model when nessesary.

## Form definition

In that case you have 3 different ways to use it as a form.

1. **Class-based generic views** - handy django shortcut. Basically, you just create a view like this:

```py
class AddPlaceView(CreateView):  
    model = Place
```

More on generic views:

- tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/
- some classes api reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/

2. **Function-based view with model form** - define a model form, based on your model and then push this to your context in your view.

```py
class PlaceForm(forms.ModelForm):  
  class Meta:  
    model = Place 
    fields = "__all__"
```

Then the view part

```py
def some_view(request):  
  form = PlaceForm()  
  return render(request, 'some_form.html', {'form': form})
```

3. A third option would be a **function-based view with regular form** solution. - Same as above, but with manual forms fields definitions (not based on model)

## HTML part - django template

After previous steps you should have a `form` variable in your template context.
First of all, include this in your head:

```
{% load mapbox_location_field_tags %} 
{% location_field_includes %}
{% include_jquery %}
```

Then you have to render this form. The code you posted is simplest way to do it, but only if you want simplest behaviour of all and all of your forms fields are defined with django forms:

```
<form method="post"> 
{% csrf_token %} 
   {{form}}
   <input type="submit" value="submit"> 
</form> 
{{ form.media }}
```

#### Render form manually - full frontend controll

Django forms also allows you to render your fields almost in every way you can think of with manual render functionality.
You can render a `location` field like this:

```
{{ form.location.errors }}
{{ form.location.label_tag }}
{{ form.location }}
```

Don't forget to append form's media:

```
{{ form.media }}
```

Some more complete code html code example:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}  

 {#     should be in head, but will probably work also this way #}  
 {% load mapbox_location_field_tags %}  
 {% location_field_includes %}  
 {% include_jquery %}  
 {#     #}
 
 <form method="post">  
 {% csrf_token %}  
 {#     some of your custom html    #}  
 <span>Enter title:</span>  
 <span class="required_field">*</span>  
 <br>  
 <input class="textbox" type="text" name="title">  
 <br>  
 <br>  
 <span>Enter description:</span>  
 <br>  
 <input class="description_box" type="text" name="description">  
 <br>  
 <br>  
  {#    and only one field generated with django forms mechanism    #}  
  {{ form.location.errors }}  
  {{ form.location.label_tag }}  
  {{ form.location }}  
  <input type="submit" value="submit">  
 </form> 
 {#    forms media  #}  
  {{ form.media }}  
{% endblock %}
```

**More on django forms, also about manual rendering on offical docs:**
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/

Hopefully, you will find this answer useful.

#### EDIT: - answer to a second question:

You can edit attributes dynamically in your view function after `form = PlaceForm()` place something like: `form.fields["location"].widget.map_attrs['center'] = (0, 0)`
Of course, replace `"location"` with your field name and `(0, 0)` with desired center geocoordinates

Comment: Please if you don't mind, how can I get my current location, using the button on the map? Because I'm trying to press this button, and unfortunately it doesn't work, it's clickable but nothing happened!

Comment: Well, it should just work. What browser do you use? Also tell me if button works in demo website:  [https://django-mapbox-location-field.herokuapp.com](https://django-mapbox-location-field.herokuapp.com)

Comment: On the demo website, it works perfectly!
I'm I tried firefox,chrome safari

Comment: Oh, it works now! I don't know why!
 Thanks
Another question please, I wanna use geo2ip to get the IP address and reverse it to lat and long then set it as a default value like the example below.
But I'm not able to know how can I pass the latitude and longitude to be as a default value for the map.
Thanks,

Comment: ```  default_map_attrs = {
            "style": "mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v11",
            "zoom": 13,
            "center": [lat, long],
            "cursor_style": 'pointer',
            "marker_color": "red",
            "rotate": False,
            "geocoder": True,
            "fullscreen_button": True,
            "navigation_buttons": True,
            "track_location_button": True,
            "readonly": True,
            "placeholder": "Pick a location on map below", }
```

Comment: about the my location button: You should check the javascript console output in your browser developers tools and look for some warning or a message. The case may be that some browser block app's GPS location request when it's an insecure HTTP connection and not HTTPS (so basically always on localhost). From what I know safari does that

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure why It works now! I'm so happy!
could you check my question about how can I pass the default latitude and longitude to the map?

Comment: You can edit attributes dynamically in your view function after `form = PlaceForm()` place something like: `form.fields["location"].widget.map_attrs['center'] = (0, 0)` Of course, replace "location" with your field name and (0, 0) with desired center geocoordinates

Comment: That was a good question actually and the solution is universal for all Django form fields, not only in my package

Comment: I don't know what to say?
It works! You made my day Szymon!